# Transforming a list of the form {{{x, y}, z}, ... } into the form {{x, y, z}, ... }

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

This should be a fairly simple question, but I can't figure out how to do it. I have a list of points of the following form:

```
{ {{x1, y1}, z1}, {{x2, y2}, z2} ... }
```

This form is useful for creating an interpolation function. However, if I want to plot a list contour plot of the same data, I need an array of the form:

```
{ {x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2} ... }
```

Is there an easy way to convert between the two, without generating the data again from scratch in the new format? I tried a few things with `Flatten[]` but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: `Flatten /@ list` or `Append @@@ list` should work.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! How is Flatten/@list different from Flatten[list,1]?

Comment: `Flatten[list,1]` basically says "get rid of all the curly braces at level 1". So, if you have a list like `{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 2}, 1}}`, the elements at level 1 are `{{1, 2}, 3}` and `{{4, 2}, 1}}`; remove the outermost braces on each of those, and splice them back into the list, you get `{{1, 2}, 3, {4, 2}, 1}`.

Comment: @J.M. Upvote for that `Append`. :)

Comment: Before this gets closed as a "Simple mistake", there's bound to be a duplicate somewhere it should point to instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's have an answer.

```
data = {{{x1, y1}, z1}, {{x2, y2}, z2}, {{x3, y3}, z3}, {{x4, y4}, z4}};
```

J.M.

```
Flatten /@ data
Append @@@ data
```

m_goldberg

```
ArrayReshape[data, {Length[data], 3}]
Block[{h}, h[{{a_, b_}, c_}] := {a, b, c}; h /@ data]
```

All of the above return

> `{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}, {x4, y4, z4}}`

Answer (score 4):

```
♭ = ## & @@@ {##} & @@@ # &;

♭ @ {{{x1, y1}, z1}, {{x2, y2}, z2}}
```

> {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}

Comment: This looks "exotic" )) +1

Answer (score 2):

another option is `Cases`

```
lst = {{{x1, y1}, z1}, {{x2, y2}, z2}}
Cases[lst, {{x__}, y__} :> {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

### Example

**Code**

```
Partition[Flatten @ data , 3]
```

**Output**

> {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}

**Note:** data is your original list

**Reference**

[Flatten](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)
[Partition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html)

Comment: Could be dangerous if any of the elements are lists themselves.

Comment: @ChipHurst I agree, but OP does not indicate such case or a need for treatment of such cases ;s

Answer (score 2):

There are many answers, but I want to give another one that could be not so elegant, but is very suitable for easy modification.
It's quite often that you have a list of "objects", where object can be a weirdly nested list, and you need to extract some subset of components possible in different order.

```
l = {{{x1, y1}, z1}, {{x2, y2}, z2}};
{#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], #[[2]]} & /@ l
```

Here it's really obvious what's happening and if you need different components, you can easily modify indices.